# Why can't we create energy/momentum by selectively measuring the spin of entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we perform a Bell violation type experiment with spin, i.e. we have a stream of entangled, spin-anticorrelated particle pairs and we are to measure their spins along different axes.

Now for each pair, we measure one particle along the x axis. If the result is +x, we measure the other particle along the z axis. If the result is -x, we do nothing. We should end up with:

1. half our particles having measured spin evenly distributed between +x and -x;
2. a quarter of our particles having measured spin evenly distributed between -z and +z;
3. a quarter of our particles unmeasured, but with the x measurement known to be +x.

Now take all those unmeasured particles and measure them along x. They will all be +x. If there are enough of them, they should have a noticeable net macroscopic angular momentum, while all the other particles cancel each other out. If they possessed this momentum the moment their partner particles were measured, the laboratory should start spinning as we conduct the experiment--violating conservation of momentum. If they do not possess it until they are measured and the measurement process transfers opposite momentum to the measuring device (i.e. if measurement by nature creates equal + and - angular momenta out of nothing), then the laboratory will be stationary, but once we measure them the measurement device and any container we put them in should begin to spin in opposite directions--preserving momentum but still violating conservation of energy.

Since spin quantization lets us choose the axis of rotation freely, and entanglement lets us pre-identify particles which WOULD spin the wrong way if measured and instead choose a different axis for them... why can't we shunt that unwanted -x momentum into the z axis "before it exists" and spin turbines without cost, dancing among rivers of free energy and creating momentum out of nothing like gods? What would actually happen if we tried to do this with vast numbers of particles?

Comment: Before a particle is measure it does not have an angular momentum. This does not mean its angular momentum is zero, it means it is undefined. Therefore there is no inherent backreaction on the measurement device on measurement as the objects angular momentum is not being "created" at that point.

Comment: None of this relies on the angular momentum being 0. Post-measurement, the particles we have measured all have 50/50 spin probabilities along the unmeasured axes, and along the measured axes they are known to be distributed 50/50 in spin direction; whereas the unmeasured ones have 50/50 probabilities along y and z, but 100/0 probabilities along x. So if, after the above, we measured every particle along a random axis, we should get a net +x momentum.

And are you sure there's no inherent backreaction? To measure, the device must be causally affected in SOME way. That's why I considered that.

Comment: "If they possessed this [angular] momentum the moment their partner particles were measured, the laboratory should start spinning as we conduct the experiment..." Why should the laboratory start spinning in that case?

Comment: Well, I put it a little bit roughly, there would of course have to be some contact to transfer momentum to the walls or what-have-you. But the point is that all the other particles' angular momenta cancel out; the imbalance comes from those unmeasured +x particles, which aren't cancelled. So if they already possessed the momentum when we measured their partners, as we continued the experiment the number of uncancelled +x particles would increase and the net angular momentum of everything in the laboratory would continually increase in the +x direction.

Comment: If they don't possess it until they themselves are actually measured in the x direction, on the other hand, during the experiment everything would on average be balanced. Only at the end when we go through all those particles we know are +x and measure their spins would there suddenly be a momentum imbalance (unless, as suggested, it can somehow be balanced by effects on the measuring instruments themselves). I'm just trying to be careful and cover all bases; knowing that a quantum measurement will have a given outcome isn't necessarily the same as the particle already having that property.